# How to return result to a partial view with kendo grid and kendo textboxes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm having a problem in returning values to my view for kendo grid & fields.

Earlier I had only kendo grid in my partial view and hence I used below code to return the values of my grid:

```
public virtual ActionResult GetValues(long Id1, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
   return Json(ViewModel.List<Another_View_Model>.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

My View Model structure is as follows

```
ViewModel 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<Another_View_Model> Another_View_Model { get; set; }
}
```

But now, I'm adding kendo textboxes, checkboxes to the same partial view and would like to return server values to those fields too while returning grid values.

My View Model structure is as follows

```
ViewModel 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public List<Another_View_Model> Another_View_Model { get; set; }
    public string textboxField { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I'm doing the following changes but my textbox field values are not returning to the view.

```
public virtual PartialViewResult GetValues(long Id1)
{
   return PartialView("_PartialView", ViewModel);
}
```

Can anyone please point me where I'm doing wrong or is there a better wayto return result for both grid & kendo elements at the same time within the same model.

My view structure is as follows:

```
@model ViewModel

  @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(p => p.textboxField)
                              .Name("TextBox")
                    )

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Another_View_Model>()
                         .Name("KendoGrid")
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i think instead of 'PartialViewResult' use 'ActionResult' and instead of 'PartialView' try 'View'

Answer (score 0):

Use either `TextBoxFor(p => p.PropertyName)` or `TextBox().Name("PropertyName")` DO NOT use both. The name property will override the TextBoxFor. So in your example, your Kendo Textbox is actually binding to a Property named `TextBox` instead of `textboxField` like you were expecting.

The inverse is also true, if you were posting a form, the Model's `textboxField` will be null, while if you had a string parameter named `TextBox` it will be populated with the textbox's value